# Is there symbolic meaning to Moses holding his hand/staff up in the air for Israel to prevail in battle (Ex. 17:11)?

Tags: moses, joshua

There are curious circumstances in the Book of Exodus, where Moses told Joshua that as he (Joshua) fought the Amalekites, Moses would sit on a hill with his staff raised in his hand:

> **Exodus 17:9-11**: "Moses said to Joshua, 'Choose men for us and go out, fight against Amalek. Tomorrow I will station myself on the top of the hill with the staff of God in my hand.' Joshua did as Moses told him, and fought against Amalek; and Moses, Aaron, and Hur went up to the top of the hill. So it came about when Moses held his hand up, that Israel prevailed, and when he let his hand down, Amalek prevailed."

Does this have any significance or symbolism to the faithful of the New Testament?

Answer (score 1):

**Is there symbolism to Moses holding his staff in the air for Israel to prevail in battle?**

Since it did not appear that feedback would be forthcoming, I discovered this pearl that seems applicable. I am unsure of its veracity:

> "As long as our hands are lifted up in praise, in worship, in thanksgiving, no matter what the circumstances, the Lord and His people will prevail. But the minute we put our hands down and stop praising God, the enemy overcomes us. In all things we have to praise God and give thanks to Jesus Christ."[1]

[1] Esses, Michael. *Jesus in Exodus,* Plainfield, N.J.,

Answer (score 1):

Alongside your answer, we have 1 Timothy 2:8

> Therefore I want the men everywhere to **pray**, **lifting** up holy hands without anger or disputing.

Luke 18:1

> And he spake a parable unto them to this end, that men ought always to **pray**, and not to faint;

Does this have any significance or symbolism to the faithful of the New Testament?

Yes indeed, it is a sign for praying faithfully before God consistently and tirelessly.

Comment: Very good point. +1

Comment: One can, of course, lift up one’s hands in different ways. The most obvious way is to stand up with lifted hands. A not so obvious way, because it is done in secret, is to elevate ones hands when in kneeling position, bent over a chair or bed.